# Drawing border around image QT.

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a few issues with this code to draw a border around an image in QT, can anyone tell me what i am missing:

```
void imageLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
QLabel::paintEvent(event);
if (!m_qImage.isNull())
{
    QImage qImageScaled =  m_qImage.scaled(QSize(width(),height()),Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation);
double dAspectRatio = (double)qImageScaled.width()/(double)m_qImage.width();
int iX = m_iX*dAspectRatio;
int iY = m_iY*dAspectRatio;
int iWidth = m_iWidth*dAspectRatio;
int iHeight = m_iHeight*dAspectRatio;

QPainter qPainter(this);
qPainter.drawImage(0,0,qImageScaled);
qPainter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
qPainter.setPen(Qt::red);
qPainter.drawRect(iX,iY,iWidth,iHeight);
}
}
```

Comment: Just to give a bit more info i am getting decleration errors with the first void decleration.... and errors with decleration regarding the m_iwidth and M_height.

Comment: If you copied this code from someplace, please remember that the variables starting with m_ usually denotes member variables that should be declared ion your class.

Comment: Do you know of any simple way to draw a rectangle around an image using qt, very new to this and have very little knowledge... sorry

Comment: OK there are 2 ways: one way is what you are doing now, by overloading the "paintEvent" of an existing widget. It leaves you to pain the frame yourself. The other is to use the widget called "QFrame"

Comment: Ok, i have had a look throught the Qt website and can see the qframe but have absoloutley no idea how to put this into a code. My image has a resolution of 344 x 59. sorry

Comment: Are you using designer? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AV9nRHJNK4

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QFrame` to simplify the task of adding a frame around a widget like `QLabel`.

In **QtCreator**, simply select the label and scroll down until you see the turquoise section of the properties editor and play with the values there.

[image: QFrame settings in properties editor of QtCreator]

The result looks like this:

[image: A QLabel with QFrame]

Hope this helps you along!